# Имеется ли простой способ поместить линию на форму WinForms?

Tags: c#, winforms, интерфейс, resources

Чтобы визуально разделить части формы, решил вставить в нескольких местах линии.

Загрузил изображение линии подходящего размера в ресурсы, но, как понимаю, теперь нужно прописать загрузку этого изображения в нужном участке формы с указанием координат.

А мне нужно сделать это несколько раз при том, что форма довольно большая.

Нет ли какого-то более простого способа вставки изображения или определения нужных координат?

Comment: wpf и layout manager? :-)

Comment: @VladD, мне кажется, я буду дольше переносить своё приложение на WPF.

Comment: Это да, но это решит и другие проблемы с лэйаутом. То есть однократная инвестиция с прибылью позже. Плюс у вас в резюме появятся новые три буквы «WPF».

Comment: Либо рисуйте линию любой длины, толщины и цвета методом [DrawLine](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/System.Drawing.Graphics.DrawLine%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) в событии [Paint](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.control.paint%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Либо используйте любой контрол-контейнер с установленной видимой границей, такие как: Panel, GroupBox, TableLayoutPanel, FlowLayoutPanel, [SplitContainer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.splitcontainer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Попробуйте другой путь:

1. Добавьте на форму `Label`.
2. Свойство `Text` сделайте пустым.
3. Установите `BorderStyle` значение `Fixed3D`.
4. Установите `AutoSize` значение `false`.
5. Установите `Height` значение 2.

Или сделайте тоже самое отдельным контролом:

```
public partial class Line : Label
{
    public override bool AutoSize
    {
        get { return false; }
    }

    public override Size MaximumSize
    {
        get { return new Size(int.MaxValue, 2); }
    }

    public override Size MinimumSize
    {
        get { return new Size(1, 2); }
    }

    public override string Text
    {
        get { return ""; }
    }

    public Line()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.AutoSize = false;
        this.Height = 2;
        this.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Fixed3D;
    }
}
```

Comment: Придумал ещё проще. Вставить Lable с текстом в духе "______". Смотрится приемлемо (в данном случае). Спасибо за идею.

Comment: @InfernumDeus тоже вариант :).

Comment: Супер, сделал с помощью Label вертикальную линию. Спасибо.